# What is mass frequency and how it arose

Tags: linear-algebra

Gaussian-profile initial condition has the solution,

$$\phi (r,t)=\frac{R^{3}}{2}\frac{A}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty
}ke^{-R^{2}k^{2}/4}\frac{\sin (kr)}{r}\cos (\omega t)\ dk,$$
From this equation the [author wrote below equation (1)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922)
that, $\omega= \left(k^2+\omega_{mass}^2\right)^{1/2}$

> Why do we consider Gaussian profile (as author stated) in linear
>   dynamics  ?
>   What is mass frequency and how do we
>   Determine the value of this frequency?

Comment: you probably know >>> http://www.dartmouth.edu/~dpsicilia/Thesis.pdf

Comment: al-Hwarizmi. the article didn't explain explicitly the mass frequency.